# Get label of vue-i18n in JS

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-i18n

In my laravel 5.6 / vue.js 2.5.7/ Bootstrap4.1.0 application I added i18n support using
https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n
plugin

It works ok, but if in vue code I use syntax, like :

```
<p>{{ $t('message.hello', {name: 'visitor'}) }}</p>
```

I would like to get label in Javascript, say in computed , as some labels depends on values of other data.

Can I do this and if yes how?

UPDATED :

I want to detalize my task:
I have editor in 2 modes for insert and update and in the template I give a parameter to other subcomponent editor-header :

```
<template>
    ...
    <editor-header  :header_title="header_title"></editor-header>
    ...

        mounted() {
    ...
            this.setAppTitle(this.header_title, false);
        }, // mounted() {
    ...

    computed: {
            header_title: function () {
//                if (!this.is_insert) return "Edit " + t("document_category.document_category");
//                return "Add "+t("document_category.document_category");
                if (!this.is_insert) return "Edit document category";
                return "Add document category";
            },
```

In my i18n files I have both labels : “Edit/Add” and “document category”, but I do not know if there is a way to manipulate as I tried in header_title.
Can it be done in some other way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, look at UPDATED block.

Comment: looks like this way : alert( "::"+( this.$t('common.do_you_want_to_delete') ) ) works ok!